# What is the malware associated with pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32, malware

I tried to download the pywin32 package off github and am unable to as my antivirus software keeps deleting it (Message is- Security risk detected: Heur.AdvML.C). It is the same complaint that was outlined in this thread:

[pywin32-220 installer "high risk" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045924/pywin32-220-installer-high-risk-file/35050079)

I have been using an the pywin32 package of python 2.7 for years but am switching to ArcPro and need to upgrade my scripts to the python 3.6 version. I need to have this to run my scripts and was hoping someone could tell me what the virus captures so we can weigh whether it is ok to download. With all the recommendations to download this, I would think someone out there would have knowledge of what the risk was.

I tried to download it from the official website:

https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Any ideas how I can get a clean version?

Many thanks

Comment: FWIW most people use `pip` for installing third-party Python packages these days, so it's unusual to install a package like `pywin32` using a standalone installer. And I thought that newer versions of Python distributions for Windows came with win32 support built in?

Comment: My script bombs out at "import win32com.client" and says it can't find the module. I did not install Python 3.6. ArcPro installed it when I installed ArcPro. I do not see it as an installed package in the ArcPro Python Package Manager so I am trying to figure out how to add it. There is an install packages option in ArcPro but I can't download pywin32 to install it.

Comment: Part of the reason for this may be that a previous version supposedly had extra code crammed into the installers by SourceForge. I'm not sure if that was even a real problem, but if people reported the pywin32-220 installer as malware, it's not too surprising that the very similar pywin32-223 installer gets a false-positive heuristic flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pywin32-220 installer "high risk" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045924/pywin32-220-installer-high-risk-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antivirus software is prone to false positives (this is a fundamental problem), so it's useful to see the big picture.

These are VirusTotal scans for all the binary downloads for the current https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b223 as of now:

- [pywin32-223.win-amd64-py2.7.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/6a30a40b964698ddf903d0ed2c2a1f3ac169e4ce084c591e69b9c2faae07dd47/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/4ca513f44351ff90925bdeeb14ecf8ec12314112acbe18d01dc02e2df3325707/detection))
- [pywin32-223.win-amd64-py3.5.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/06417dad2214d2e5f31349dece85e1f76f3f20af2058fa7b0e9c7e925f312112/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/29c4eb407d52bd3bad3fa6cd9da556f95eb1bee7f0e2391262c7d6e7d87aec32/detection) 1)
- [pywin32-223.win-amd64-py3.6.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/5c002bdfcc8f1c661fb5e3438508f165b8b2c70a6ed6e7559192b45cd4afad5c/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/06570883d3c036a90380903ad553f89b8406b9f2871d9a46f738ffb38e02dc19/detection))
- [pywin32-223.win-amd64-py3.7.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/a880563c9c6d5c48a56f62e6f78bfb386f1fe14d5e4ffd4f9a98515dabd10c8c/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/863f97e2df9a5d9c9d87665fc587bbb5e5e17af36ed518d76670932e51613f4e/detection))
- [pywin32-223.win32-py2.7.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/002ffc29ce73f5f1065cfe60b1d80d66d6d3da9c872f2cd80bd1215a91705670/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/2acbb9a1ce0f4d86b34f6b5991ba5b57143309c6cf732bb85c6114e9229c6e99/detection))
- [pywin32-223.win32-py3.5.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/cc0f847d46640c19f21cc5be04e1cc14534efcb143013e8e5201340142181cff/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/43ef5ae23a053dd5ce42cd86569e49d2ff11f879848fcb4b9bfbfbe53b6dffbe/detection))
- [pywin32-223.win32-py3.6.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/a5c846a84e5da16586077ebd9031709c0c2872ed443ae1aa62308884ebeac06b/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/34d3e7149f539c4eb7e76990f7b89519708c257b1e2856931db9f8253815bfb7/detection) 1)
- [pywin32-223.win32-py3.7.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/f7eb446e6437a27c04b73bd64cc6415f98cddddd95cecb9865a669ef87e74493/detection) ([URL](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/498df1f69833d9c27558e89b3a97afeaafce89c17cca6ce91e9a52b152bf4382/detection))

As you can see, download URLs are checked separately, there are no positives for files but there are some select ones for URLs. Since the files are okay, these must be false positives.

Answer (score 1):

[`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) has been `pip`-installable for quite some time now. And there are some advantages to installing that way:

- It avoids this antivirus problem.
- This is the same way you install every other Python package in 2018.
- `pip` can upgrade it, install it into virtual environments (even different versions in different environments), etc.

---

But there are also some disadvantages:

- Running `pip` as a normal user can't run the post-install script with elevated privileges. As the docs say, "if you want to use pywin32 for "system wide" features, such as registering COM objects or implementing Windows Services, then you must run the following command from an elevated command prompt: `python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install`.
- `pip` support is still considered "experimental". I haven't heard of any problems, but this means that if you have a problem and ask for help, you may be asked to `pip uninstall` it and install it the officially-recommended way (grabbing an installer package from the Releases page and running it).

---

One more option worth considering—probably not relevant if you're using ArcPro, but maybe for other people reading this question—is using Anaconda Python instead of a different Python.

Anaconda comes with `pywin32` pre-installed. Miniconda can install it with `conda install pywin32`. While this isn't officially supported by the pywin32 team, it *is* supported and tested by the Anaconda team.

Comment: Last time I checked, the `pip` installer for `pywin32` didn't do the postinstall steps that `bdist_wininst` does like copying DLLs to `%windir%` and registering COM classes. As a result, some modules were unusable. Has this been fixed since?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The first of the "some disadvantages" in my answer is a summary of what the docs say about that (as of version 223). You can read the full details in the README or docs. I believe they at least print out a message with a similar summary at the end of a `pip install`, but it seemed better to explain that here than to rely on people reading that message.

Answer (score 0):

The name `Heur.AdvML.C` probably breaks down as:

- `Heur`: This is a "heuristic" detection event. In other words, the antivirus software doesn't see anything matching a known signature, but the file looks suspicious according to a rule-of-thumb that has been programmed into it.
- `AdvML`: The rule of thumb in question is some kind of "Advanced Machine Learning" algorithm. The AV software authors trained some kind of neural network classifier or something on a bunch of example malicious and non-malicious files, and that classifier now thinks this file looks more like the malicious files than the non-malicious ones.
- `C`: AV software writers like to name malware in series (`.A`, `.B`, `.C`); your AV program thinks this is the third in such a series. Maybe the file was detected by the third of a series of classifiers that it uses?

Anyway, it's not the name of a "real" virus, just a code that lets you know a bit about why/how the AV software determined that the file is suspicious. If you got the file over a secure connection from a trusted source, your AV software is probably wrong.